# Can't delete a row from an sqlite database.. any ideas?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I have an sqlite database which is displayed on a datagrid.
I'm executing the query without any exceptions but the records are not deleted.
I'm also having trouble to update the records too.
any ideas? 
here is what I coded:

```
 private void EraseRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Delete from Activity where RowID=5", _conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        ActivitiesDataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataBase.updateDataGrid(_conn);
        _conn.Close();
    }

     public ObservableCollection<Activity> updateDataGrid(SQLiteConnection _sqlConnect)

        {

            List<Activity> _actList = new List<Activity>();

            SQLiteCommand cmd01 = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Activity", _sqlConnect);

            SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd01.ExecuteReader();

            ObservableCollection<Activity> _activitiesList= new ObservableCollection<Activity>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                Activity _act = new Activity();

                _act.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Activity"));

                _act.Customer = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ActivityCustomer"));

                string _actST = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ActivityNature"));

                _act.Activitytpe = (ActivityType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ActivityType), _actST);

                string st = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("StartedAt"));

                _act.StartedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(st);

                string et = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FinishedAt"));

                _act.EndedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(et);

                //string _ratio = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ActivityRatio"));
                //_act.ActivityRatio = Convert.ToDouble(_ratio);
                _act.Notes = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Notes"));

                string _hldy = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Holiday"));

                _act.IsHoliday = Convert.ToBoolean(_hldy);

                _activitiesList.Add(_act);
            }

            return _activitiesList;
            //_adpt01.Fill(_tbl01);
            //dgrid.ItemsSource = _tbl01.DefaultView;
            //Disconnect(_sqlConnect);

        }
```

Comment: Are you getting a error?, We cannot guess what "having trouble" means

Comment: The problem is that i'm not having any errors. I'm meaning by having trouble the fact that I'm not having any indications where the problem might be.

Comment: While I'm testing I noticed the following: I was able to delete only one time, then records stayed the same.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are ever sending **RowID=5**

Comment: I'm sure it contains more than 5 rows. only using 5 for testing

Comment: I found a solution after a little research. When performing a delete query, rowid's do not update to their new values. A vacuum command gets everything into place as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better way than the "vacuum" command, which feels like using a nuke to swat a fly. According to the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html), the Vacuum command rebuilds the *entire database* and is intended to fix issues with db file fragmentation that can arise over time. In fact, the ROWID behavior you reference is only mentioned in passing:

> The VACUUM command **may** change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables
>   that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

(emphasis mine -- the word "may" in there means "don't write code that depends on this behavior").

Without knowing why the RowID 5 is special to your application, it's difficult to suggest a better answer. If you always want to delete the 5th-oldest row, you might execute a command like

```
delete from Activity where RowID = (
    select max(RowID) from (select RowID from Activity order by RowID limit 5)
);
```

This command may not be exactly what you want (it will delete the 4th-oldest if there are only four rows, and the sole row if there is only one). But hopefully it gives you an idea for how to accomplish what you want in a more direct and explicit way than rebuilding the entire database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clears lots of things about the vacuum command. I used RowID 5 only for testing. Normally it's the RowID of the selected datagrid item.